# rosmake error: [rospack] Error: package/stack depends on non-existent package opencv2

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.

I got a problem since today after updating my ubuntu 12.04 today (-> update manager -> install updates)

[rospack] Error: package/stack openCVbridge depends on non-existent package opencv2

How can i solve this? Thx!

---

---

> cheese@wtmgws1:~/Diplom/code/openCVbridge$ rosmake
> [ rosmake ] rosmake starting...
> [ rosmake ] No package specified.  Building ['openCVbridge']
> [ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['openCVbridge']
> [ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/cheese/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130625-155021
> [ rosmake ] Expanded args ['openCVbridge'] to:
> ['openCVbridge']
> [rosmake-0] Starting >>> geometry_msgs [ make ]
> [rosmake-1] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]
> [rosmake-0] Finished <<< geometry_msgs  No Makefile in package geometry_msgs
> [rosmake-0] Starting >>> sensor_msgs [ make ]
> [rosmake-2] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]
> [rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosbuild [ make ]
> [rosmake-1] Finished <<< roslang  No Makefile in package roslang
> [rosmake-1] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]
> [rosmake-0] Finished <<< sensor_msgs  No Makefile in package sensor_msgs
> [rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]
> [rosmake-2] Finished <<< std_msgs  No Makefile in package std_msgs
> [rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]
> [rosmake-4] Starting >>> message_filters [ make ]
> [rosmake-5] Starting >>> openCVbridge [ make ]
> [rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosbuild  No Makefile in package rosbuild
> [rosmake-1] Finished <<< roscpp  No Makefile in package roscpp
> [rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslib  No Makefile in package roslib
> [rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosconsole  No Makefile in package rosconsole
> [rosmake-4] Finished <<< message_filters  No Makefile in package message_filters
> [rosmake-1] Starting >>> pluginlib [ make ]
> [rosmake-1] Finished <<< pluginlib ROS_NOBUILD in package pluginlib
> [rosmake-1] Starting >>> image_transport [ make ]
> [rosmake-1] Finished <<< image_transport ROS_NOBUILD in package image_transport
> [ rosmake ] All 21 linespenCVbridge: 0.7 sec ]                                                                 [ 1 Active 11/12 Complete ]
> {-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> mkdir -p bin
> cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
> [rosbuild] Building package openCVbridge
> Failed to invoke /opt/ros/fuerte/bin/rospack deps-manifests openCVbridge
> [rospack] Error: package/stack openCVbridge depends on non-existent package opencv2

CMake Error at /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message):

```
Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package 'openCVbridge'.                                                             
Look above for errors from rospack itself.  Aborting.  Please fix the
broken dependency!
```

Call Stack (most recent call first):
/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:203 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
CMakeLists.txt:12 (rosbuild_init)

### -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

[ rosmake ] Output from build of package openCVbridge written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/cheese/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130625-155021/openCVbridge/build_output.log
[rosmake-5] Finished <<< openCVbridge [FAIL] [ 0.73 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package openCVbridge.
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Results:
[ rosmake ] Built 12 packages with 1 failures.
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory
[ rosmake ] /home/cheese/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130625-155021

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65892/rosmake-error:-%5Brospack%5D-error:-package/stack-depends-on-non-existent-package-opencv2/) by [HubbaW](https://answers.ros.org/users/5230/hubbaw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-06-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This means that the package opencv2 is not in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.  Please make sure it is there.  What is your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH and where do you find opencv2 on your system?

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [HubbaW](https://answers.ros.org/users/5230/hubbaw/) on 2013-06-27**:
i checked everything twice. opencv is included in the package-path. i solved the problem by adding "find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)" in the CmakeList.txt and deleting "" from manifest.xml